# Is there a way to get message by correlation Id without use any of the point to point sampler?

Tags: jmeter

I am able to use two JSR223 samplers one for produce and one for consume without any issue (no JNDI setup).

Now, I would like to know is there a way to validate the received message content filter by correlation Id?

For example, my sampler 1 produced 100 msg with 100 different correlationId, then how my second sampler can get the correlation Id from the 1 sampler and validate the content?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`message.getJMSCorrelationID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSCorrelationID--) function in first sampler in conjunction with [`vars.put()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) in order to retrieve the correlationID from the message and store it into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

```
vars.put('correlationId', message.getJMSCorrelationID())
```

and in 2nd sampler use [`vars.get()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get-java.lang.String-) to retrieve the value in 2nd sampler

```
def correlationId = vars.get('correlationId')
```

Check out [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how) article for an example implementation of MQ load testing using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language

Comment: ya, that is the one I followed, will this way lose message? or it will only consume the one which match the id and the rest of the message will stay in the queue?